# Firebird database keeps getting larger

Tags: firebird, firebird1.5

This one is interesting to me - despite the almost inane title. I have used Firebird for a long time, but not until recently noticed an interesting behavior.

I am using embedded Firebird 1.5, and noticed that if I stuff the database full of blobs (lets say 10mb worth), the size of the database increases. I can then delete all the fields in the database, and the file size of the DB remains at its expanded size. Currently it is at 20mb and is completely empty.

I know that Firebird has this built into its architecture (for quick indexing, speed issues etc), but I always thought it would decrease back down to its original ~2mb default.

Does anyone have any suggestions to 'deflate' the file size? The reason being is that this is a space conscious issue. If I had tons of space to work with, I wouldn't care. However that is not the case, and I need things to be as optimal as possible

Comment: It's good manners on SO to accept an answer you find useful by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to free unused space in a Firebird database is to do a backup then an immediate restore of that backup (Reference: [Firebird FAQ](https://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq41/)).

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200128174156/http://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/search/doc_23) is a good technical explanation of why this is so.

Note that Firebird will reuse the currently unused space - i.e. if you put another 10MB of blobs in now, the database should not grow to 30MB.

Comment: thanks for the answer - but what if the size of the database is due to use. Such as storing values in it, or blobs. A user uses the db for a while, and I would like it to be resized back down to its 2mb default (with all of info retained) if it doesn't need to be 20mb. Does that make sense? Maybe I am not following your logic?

Comment: Updated my answer. Basically, there's no way apart from backup/restore. You could script this as a nightly/weekly task maybe?

Comment: Thanks! I have read that page /minus/ the bottom part that mentions the backup/restore. Makes sense though, with how complicated the pointers are within the paging system. Thanks for taking the time and effort to post, and point me to the backup/restore part of the article.

Comment: Can you not get similar results by forcing a Sweep using gfix?  I thought a B&R was a last resort option.